# Prove that a certain set is a halfplane.

Tags: geometry, real-numbers, plane-geometry

> Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(a,b)\ne0$. Prove that the set $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: ax+by+c\le0\}$ is a halfplane of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I'm a bit confused by this exercise, For what I know the definition of halfplane is what I'm asked to prove (the book does not give a definition of halfplane), searching on the web I found:

> A half-plane is a planar region consisting of all points on one side of an infinite straight line, and no points on the other side. (Wolfram Alpha)
>
> Either half of an infinite plane (divided by a straight line). (Wiktionary)

...and other similar definitions; but I don't know how to prove the assertion using these.

Can you give me a hint? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $b>0$, then $S$ is the same as the set of all $(x,y)$ with $y\le (-a/b)x+(-c/a)$, that is the set of points below the line $y=(-a/b)x+(-c/b)$.

Likewise, if $b<0$ then $S$ is the set of points above some line.

If $b=0$, then $S$ is the set of points to the right of, or to the left of,
some vertical line.

Comment: Thanks, but this is an 'intuitive' argument rather than a rigorous one, right?

Answer (score 1):

A half plane in $ \mathbb R^2$ is defined as follows: given a linear functional $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $d \in \mathbb R$, the set

$H=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: f(x,y) \le d\}$

is called a half plane.

For your set $S$ take $f(x,y)=ax+by$ and $d=-c$.